# Не могу использовать адаптер вайфай на убунту

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, adapter

Я полный новичек в использовании линукс. Пытаюсь подключить usb wifi адаптер (Tenda Model: W311MI ) к ноутбуку на

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

Сразу после подключения я вижу этот адаптер в настройках сети, но он появляется и пропадает каждую секунду.
В комплекте с адаптером идут драйвера в формате exe, которые мне не удалось утсановить на линукс. Я немного почитал о ndiswrapper но это сложно и я надеюсь что не дойдет до его использования.

Вот немного информации при подключенном адаптере которую просят предоставить в подобных вопросах:

```
inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.8 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20236 v: Lenovo G500 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: INVALID v: 00000000Not Defined serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: 78CN25WW(V2.03) 
           date: 11/19/2013 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 24.9 Wh condition: 43.4/38.9 Wh (112%) model: LENOVO PABAS0241231 status: Unknown 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Pentium 2020M bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9 L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 9577 
           Speed: 2390 MHz min/max: 1200/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2376 2: 2377 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1) v: 4.2 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-58-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: alx v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter driver: bcma-pci-bridge v: N/A 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF-ID-1: br-df5b27187d8c state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-3: surfshark_ipv6 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-4: surfshark_wg state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A 
           IF-ID-5: wlp2s0b1 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 61.29 GiB (13.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST500LT012-1DG142 size: 465.76 GiB temp: 43 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 456.89 GiB used: 61.29 GiB (13.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 66.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 265 Uptime: 1h 30m Memory: 7.66 GiB used: 3.58 GiB (46.7%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.4.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38 
CODE: SELECT ALL

rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no


iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Kyivstar-F960"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 04:5E:A4:07:F9:67   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:1669   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-df5b27187d8c  no wireless extensions.

surfshark_ipv6  no wireless extensions.

surfshark_wg  no wireless extensions.


lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM70 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 18f8:0f97 [Maxxter] USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/bcm4313

Comment: мне просто нужно выполнить по очереди все команды которые Вы дали в ссылке? я просто в этом еще ничего не понимаю

Comment: выполнил все пункты по Вашей ссылке на пункта 4 make
выдает что нет прав Permission denied

Comment: надо под рутом.

Comment: это как? я ничего не знаю про убунту